# How to display a time in the user's local time zone if I have that time in UTC?

Tags: django, timezone

The user has entered a time and we are saving it in UTC. We would like to display this time back to the user using the template language after submission, in their own time zone.

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646662/how-to-handle-datetimes-from-different-timezones/17648786#17648786) maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the method [`localtime`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#localtime):

```
{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}
```

Comment: We tried that out before posting but it shows just blank content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the user's timezone yourself. Then, you can just do this:

```
{% load tz %}
{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ object.date }}
{% endtimezone %}
```